# Keep getting "possible lossy conversion from double to int" error in Java

Tags: java

```
public static int calcCarbonFootprint ( double[] person ) {

    double kgCO2;
    double metricTons;
    kgCO2 = (double)(calcTransit(person[3]));
    kgCO2 += (double)calcAutoOwnership(person[2]);
    kgCO2 += (double)calcAutoUsage(person[0],person[1]);
    metricTons = kgCO2/KGS_PER_METRIC_TON;

    return (int)metricTons;
}
```

This is the function I'm trying to add, but I keep getting these errors:

```
./CarbonCalculator.java:142: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    kgCO2 = (double)(calcTransit(person[3]));
                                       ^
./CarbonCalculator.java:143: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    kgCO2 += (double)calcAutoOwnership(person[2]);
                                             ^
./CarbonCalculator.java:144: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    kgCO2 += (double)calcAutoUsage(person[0],person[1]);
                                                   ^
```

I've tried many different approaches, but all end up in the same error. Could I get some direction?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm not sure what that means entirely.

Comment: Why does `calcCarbonFootprint` return `int`? Why not return a `double`?

Comment: see `Double::intValue` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue()

Comment: That's what my instructions say, I'm not sure.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. The problem was that the functions I was calling used integers as parameters, while I was trying to use doubles. I changed "person[KMS_TRANSIT_INDEX]" to "(int)person[KMS_TRANSIT_INDEX]" and it worked'

Comment: use `return (double)metricTons;` , its lossy means you will lose value or precision if you use int.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by attempting to pass a `double` number, which has 64-bits, to an `int` argument, that has 32 bits.

You can change the parameters of your `calc*` methods to accept `double` instead of `int`. This way the calculation will be as precise as possible.

... or you can cast `person[n]` to `int`. Some numerical data from the `double` type number will disappear, along with the accuracy of the calculation methods.

Example code: https://ideone.com/ghgRo9